# Get class member by its name

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

I need get a member of a class within the class.

In MainForm (class with Design) I have a lot of ComboBox and TextBox, so write name one per one is very uncomfortable, I think it's possible but no sure.

for ilustrate, suppose I have 10 ComboBox all with name 'cb_0..9' instead of write name of all ComboBox I want to access SelectedIndex within a for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   this.GetMember("cb_" + i).SelectedIndex = 1;
}
```

Is this possible and is simple to do ?

Comment: What is `GetMember`, what type does it return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  You will need to cast the control to be able to use it as a ComboBox, e.g.

```
((ComboBox)this.Controls["cb_" + i]).SelectedIndex = 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
  ((ComboBox)FindControl(string.Format("cb_{0}", i))).SelectedIndex=1;
```

I haven't ran this code - so it might not be perfect - but a good starting point